# Filling a hash with parsed input elements

Tags: perl, hash, element

I would like to take a given input, say , and run specific parsings over it and fill a hash with the outputs of those parsings. For example, I'd like this input:

```
"barcodedSamples": "{\"I-735\":{\"barcodes\":[\"IonXpress_001\"]},\"13055\":{\"barcodes\":[\"IonXpress_002\"]}}",
```

to be parsed (using a combination of grep and some more specific fiddling that I don't have a strong grasp on) into a table that lists the barcodes and sample names as follows:

```
barcode         sample
IonXpress_001   I-735
IonXpress_002   13055
```

where "barcode" and "sample" are treated as keys. Another example is that I would like to grep to a line that starts:

```
"library": "hg19",
```

and map the value "hg19" (so, the string inside the second set of quotation marks, programmatically speaking) to an arbitrary key like "lib":

```
Library
hg19
```

Answer (score 3):

The string closely resembles JSON, however requires some cleaning up to become valid JSON.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => qw/all/;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $json_string = '"barcodedSamples": "{\"I-735\":{\"barcodes\":[\"IonXpress_001\"]},\"13055\":{\"barcodes\":[\"IonXpress_002\"]}}"';

$json_string =~ s/\\//g;                 # remove escape backslashes.
$json_string =~ s/"\{/{/;                # remove an invalid opening quote.
chop $json_string;                       # remove an invalid closing quote.
$json_string = '{' . $json_string . '}'; # wrap in curly braces.

my $json_object = JSON->new( );

my $perl_ref = $json_object->decode( $json_string );

print Dumper( $perl_ref );
```

Answer (score 1):

That string you're parsing looks suspiciously like JSON.  Why not just use the JSON module (which comes with newer Perls, but can be installed from CPAN for older ones) instead of writing your own parser?

Comment: I will be extracting data from several different sources, some which are JSON-y, some which aren't. Helpful suggestion though, thanks!